# Does the function multinom() from R's nnet package fit a multinomial logistic regression, or a Poisson regression?

Tags: r, poisson, multinomial, nnet

The documentation for the multinom() function from the nnet package in R says that it "[f]its multinomial log-linear models via neural networks" and that "[t]he response should be a factor or a matrix with K columns, which will be interpreted as counts for each of K classes." Even when I go to add a tag for nnet on this question, the description says that it is software for fitting "multinomial log-linear models."

Granting that statistics has wildly inconsistent jargon that is rarely operationally defined by whoever is using it, the documentation for the function even mentions having a count response and so seems to indicate that this function is designed to model count data. Yet virtually every resource I've seen treats it exclusively as if it were fitting a multinomial logistic regression. In short, everyone interprets the results in terms of logged odds relative to the reference (as in logistic regression), *not* in terms of logged expected count (as in what is typically referred to as a log-linear model).

Can someone clarify what this function is actually doing and what the fitted coefficients actually mean?

Comment: Consider posting this question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Or email the maintainer directly. Interesting!

Answer (score -1):

`nnet::multinom` is fitting a multinomial logistic regression as I understand...

If you check the source code of the package, https://github.com/cran/nnet/blob/master/R/multinom.R and https://github.com/cran/nnet/blob/master/R/nnet.R, you will see that the multinom function is indeed using counts (which is a common thing to use as input for a multinomial regression model, see also the `MGLM` or `mclogit` package e.g.), and that it is fitting the multinomial regression model using a softmax transform to go from predictions on the additive log-ratio scale to predicted probabilities. The softmax transform is indeed the inverse link scale of a multinomial regression model. The way the multinom model predictions are obtained, cf.[predictions from nnet::multinom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044314/predictions-from-nnetmultinom), is also exactly as you would expect for a multinomial regression model (using an additive log-ratio scale parameterization, i.e. using one outcome category as a baseline).
That is, the coefficients predict the logged odds relative to the reference baseline category (i.e. it is doing a logistic regression), not the logged expected counts (like a log-linear model).
This is shown by the fact that model predictions are calculated as

```
fit <- nnet::multinom(...)
X <- model.matrix(fit) # covariate matrix / design matrix
betahat <- t(rbind(0, coef(fit))) # model coefficients, with expicit zero row added for reference category & transposed
preds <- mclustAddons::softmax(X %*% betahat)
```

Furthermore, I verified that the `vcov` matrix returned by `nnet::multinom` matches that when I use the formula for the `vcov` matrix of a multinomial regression model, [Faster way to calculate the Hessian / Fisher Information Matrix of a nnet::multinom multinomial regression in R using Rcpp & Kronecker products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811835/faster-way-to-calculate-the-hessian-fisher-information-matrix-of-a-nnetmulti).

Is it not the case that a multinomial regression model can always be reformulated as a Poisson loglinear model (i.e. as a Poisson GLM) using the Poisson trick (`glmnet` e.g. uses the Poisson trick to fit multinomial regression models as a Poisson GLM)?